# Work Around Android WiFi Throttling Restrictions?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-wifi

Per [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan):

> The following limitations apply to the frequency of scans using WifiManager.startScan().
>
> Android 8.0 and Android 8.1: Each background app can scan one time in a 30-minute period.
>
> Android 9: Each foreground app can scan four times in a 2-minute period. This allows for a burst of scans in a short time. All background apps combined can scan one time in a 30-minute period.
>
> Android 10 and higher: The same throttling limits from Android 9 apply. There is a new developer option to toggle the throttling off for local testing (under Developer Options > Networking > Wi-Fi scan throttling).

So if we want to build a sensor app (for particular SSIDs, BSSIDs, etc.) for users, the best rate we can hope for is a single scan every half-hour?

My aim was to spawn several recurring workers using WorkManager and WorkRequests to get the frequency down to something more reasonable (e.g. 5 minutes), until I saw the above limitation.  Is there no workaround to this restriction?

Comment: In other words, this restriction seems too restrictive to be believable, so I hope I'm reading it wrong or there exists some better practice for these types of apps.

Comment: Typically (though not universally), when the docs refer to a "foreground app", that includes foreground services. So, you might give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from CommonsWare led me on the right direction.  I had to restructure my entire app as a foreground service (not foreground app, as I still want it to be able to run indefinitely in the background).  Once I did that, I was able to scan for WiFi networks every 4 minutes for at least 50 minutes straight.  [This](https://robertohuertas.com/2019/06/29/android_foreground_services/) was the most helpful resource.